# Send MP3 file via RTP

Tags: streaming, mp3, audio-streaming, rtp

I want to send a file .mp3 in RTP packets to a client. What I know is, how many bytes I get from .mp3 file to send in each RTP packet, that is, how much bytes of the .mp3 file I place in the payload field of each RTP packet?

Thanks for the help.

Greetings!

Comment: Did you manage to send the mp3 file?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [RFC 5219](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc5219.html) - A More Loss-Tolerant RTP Payload Format for MP3 Audio.
It's not as simple as "how many bytes...".  This also references the older RFCs for MP3.

Comment: You're right jesup, I've been looking at the documentation and it seems, to calculate the number of bytes that I have to send each datagram, I have to do a calculation from the header information of the start of the file.

Let me explain. It seems that the header of an MP3 file occupies 32 bytes, so when you open the file I have to read the first 32 bytes to learn (reading this header fields) the remaining bytes that I have to catch the first datagram . This same process I do for the next set of bytes.